# PyCharm run button is not working. How may I solve it?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to python. PyCharm was working just fine. But I don't know what changes I made, its run button is not working. Can anyone help? [Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8xFr.png)

Comment: cant shift+f10?

Comment: Press Run, then a menu will appear, choose from that

Comment: Your code is good, show us what it displays after you press run

Comment: you have to add configuration for python or python virtual environment.
click add config in the left side of the run button and add python path, it'll run I think.

Comment: have you selected python interpreter? probable reason is, pycharm doesn't know any python interpreter to use.

Comment: you have to add a configuration first

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes No it's not working like that.

Comment: @SaianshSingh run button used to work. But now it's not working anymore. That is the main issue here.

Comment: @Tasnuva It was working just 1 hour ago. I don't know what exactly is changed. Is there any way I can check or select the interpreter?

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson It was configured. Not sure what happened.

Comment: @hosainabid , just manually click on the run button on the top most tab near the button `Refactor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because you do not have a configuration to run the program. Here's how to add a configuration -

[Step 1 - click the add configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY2CN.png)

[Step 2 - click the plus sign to add the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWveb.png)

[Step 3 - click 'Python'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA0Bh.png)

[Step 4 - Add your script path and your interpreter path. Then, click Apply and Ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6suE.png)

Now, you can run the script.

Remember, if you run a new file under the same project, make a new configuration with the path of the new file